# wired problem of ext4 filesystem: ext4_init_inode_table always has error, but e2fsck cannot fix it

Tags: ext4

I had a dumped ext4 partition image: mmcblk0p5
I can mount the image, but it always read-only. So I checked the dmesg, there is something like this:

```
EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_init_inode_table:1340: comm ext4lazyinit: Something is wrong with group 0: used itable blocks: 467; itable unused count: 0
```

So I run a `e2fsck -ccy mmcblk0p5`

```
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
mmcblk0p5: recovering journal
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
mmcblk0p5: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

mmcblk0p5: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
mmcblk0p5: 1623/44802 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 138293/179194 blocks
```

It seems cannot find any error but just clear out the error log. If I mount it again same error shows up. How can I fix this file system? Here is tune2fs result after mount/umount the image file.

```
tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /system
Filesystem UUID:          57f8f4bc-abf4-0000-675f-946fc0f9f25b
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal resize_inode filetype needs_recovery extent sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         unsigned_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean with errors
Errors behavior:          Remount read-only
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              44802
Block count:              179194
Reserved block count:     0
Free blocks:              40901
Free inodes:              43179
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      47
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         7467
Inode blocks per group:   467
Last mount time:          Tue Oct 25 18:13:08 2016
Last write time:          Tue Oct 25 18:13:10 2016
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Oct 25 18:09:34 2016
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          94 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   tea
Journal backup:           inode blocks
FS Error count:           2
First error time:         Tue Oct 25 18:13:10 2016
First error function:     ext4_init_inode_table
First error line #:       1340
First error inode #:      0
First error block #:      0
Last error time:          Tue Oct 25 18:13:10 2016
Last error function:      ext4_init_inode_table
Last error line #:        1383
Last error inode #:       0
Last error block #:       0
```

If I do `tune2fs -e continue mmcblk0p5`. Then mount and create some folders onto it. the e2fsck will give out some error:

```
e2fsck -ccky mmcblk0p5
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                                 
mmcblk0p5: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Inode bitmap differences:  -29845 +29869
Fix? yes


mmcblk0p5: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
mmcblk0p5: 1624/44802 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 138294/179194 blocks
```

But this error cannot be fixed, it always there. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Any device mounted as loop? `device loop0`

Comment: sure the file mmcblk0p5 mount as loop0

Comment: Is on mmcblk0p5 an image-file? I know mount on /dev/loop only with iso's or image-files. `lsblk -f`

Comment: it is not an iso image. It is a disk image. I can mount other disk image as writeable for sure.